# How to receive input for mocked ink_env::test::ChainExtension

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I'm trying to write an off-chain test for an ink! smart-contract that uses chain extensions. The [example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/examples/rand-extension/lib.rs) showing how to mock an extension for tests is never using the supplied `_input` argument.

The functions of my chain extension have the following signatures:

```
#[ink::chain_extension]
pub trait BalanceExtension {
    type ErrorCode = BalanceReadErr;

    #[ink(extension = 1101, returns_result = false)]
    fn fetch_balance(owner: ink_env::AccountId, asset: Asset) -> u128;

    #[ink(extension = 1102, returns_result = false, handle_status = false)]
    fn transfer_balance(
        from: ink_env::AccountId,
        to: ink_env::AccountId,
        asset: Asset,
        amount: u128,
    ) -> ();
}
```

.

For the tests I created a mock as follows:

```
        type FetchBalanceInput = [u8; 32 + 32 + 12]; // 1-> owner:AccountId, 2-> asset_issuer: [u8;32], 3-> asset_code: [u8;12]

        struct MockedBalanceExtension {
            balances: Rc<RefCell<BalanceMapping>>,
        }

        impl ink_env::test::ChainExtension for MockedBalanceExtension {
            /// The static function id of the chain extension.
            fn func_id(&self) -> u32 {
                1101
            }

            fn call(&mut self, mut _input: &[u8], output: &mut Vec<u8>) -> u32 {
                // log input by panicking
                // panic!("input: {:?}, length: {:?}", _input, _input.len(),);
                let input: FetchBalanceInput =
                    <FetchBalanceInput as scale::Decode>::decode(&mut input).unwrap();

                let mut account_array: [u8; 32] = Default::default();
                account_array.copy_from_slice(&input[0..32]);
                let account_id = AccountId::from(account_array);

                let mut issuer_array: [u8; 32] = Default::default();
                issuer_array.copy_from_slice(&input[32..64]);

                let mut asset_code_array: [u8; 12] = Default::default();
                asset_code_array.copy_from_slice(&input[64..]);

                let asset: Asset = (issuer_array, asset_code_array);

                let map = self.balances.borrow_mut();
                let balance = map.get(&(account_id, asset)).unwrap_or_else(|| {
                    panic!(
                        "No entry found for account_id: {:?}, asset: {:?}",
                        account_id, asset,
                    )
                });

                scale::Encode::encode_to(&balance, output);

                0 // 0 is error code
            }
        }
```

Now when I test my smart contract and call the `fetch_balance` function with the following arguments:

```
let account_id = AccountId::from([0x01; 32]);
let asset = ([0x02; 32], [0x03; 12]);
fetch_balance(account_id, asset);
```

the panic! logs an input of  `[49, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and I don't understand why. The 32x `1`s are obviously from the account_id but the passed `asset` argument is completely ignored and also what does the leading `49` mean?

I looked a bit into the implementation of the chain extension and it seems that the `_input` that is passed to the `call()` is encoded beforehand, so I tried to decode it. But I logged both the passed `_input` without decoding it and with decoding (like shown in the snippet) and it does not change much.

Has someone experience with testing a chain extension of ink! smart contracts while using the provided input argument? Am I missing something here? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: For me all arguments are encoded correctly, but I need to skip the first few bytes. The number of bytes I need to skip is different depending on arguments, and I can't figure out what the first few bytes are for.

Comment: Try adding the chain-extension tag. I want an answer to this also.

Comment: I found the answer by digging through the source code. :D

Comment: I also noticed that I can just skip the first two bytes and the rest is the data I'm looking for without having to call decode(). But I didn't notice that it depends on the arguments. I would also be curious as to why this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is encoded again to a vector of bytes, so you can decode it like this:

```
let bytes: Vec<u8> = Decode::decode(&mut &input[..]).unwrap();
let (owner, asset): (AccountId, Asset) = Decode::decode(&mut &bytes[..]).unwrap();
```

You can see a working example [here](https://github.com/efinity/wasm-conf-demo/blob/master/src/mock.rs).

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing that example. Happy to see another project using and testing with chain extensions. You can find the code I used for solving it [here](https://github.com/pendulum-chain/pendulum-amm/blob/master/smart_contract/src/lib.rs#L981).